# Return different objects depending upon the number of items in the list

Tags: java, jdbc

I am in a situation where I want to fetch the data from a bd table using jdbc. I have written a basic jdbc code where I try am running a select query. I have made a dao function which runs the select query and gets the data into ResultSet(). I insert this data into the object List to a matching model and return a list of these model Objects as the return of this select query can have multiple rows.

Now, I call this method into a different class which returns me a List from which I can get the data by looping through the List. Most of the times the query contains one row and while calling the dao function I always have to loop the list even if it contains one row. Is there a dynamic way by which this same dao function returns the List of model objects if there are multiple rows in result set AND return only one model object if there is just one row. This will save me the frustration of looping through the returned list always even if only one row is returned.

Comment: Why not just keep it as a list and re-use the code instead of having to write *additional* code, in multiple places, to handle the variance?

Comment: Short answer: no. Anyways, how is looping through one-element list more frustrating than say a hundred-element list? Code should be exactly the same.

Comment: "Save me the frustration of looping through" why does it frustrate you? If the list is size one, it will not be slow. If it gets the job done, what is wrong?.

Comment: You should instead write another DAO method, that would be called when the caller knows that the query must return only a single element. This method would delegate to the first one, check that the returned list has only one element (and throw an exception if it doesn't), and return the single element of the list.